# What is the correct form of the HostnameSuffixes SSH keyword?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I came across an SSH configuration setting that I've never seen before while following [a discussion on an OpenSSH developers' mailing list archive](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/55471).  The [particular setting](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/55471#55471) is this:

```
Host * 
HostnameSuffixes foo.com ext.foo.com
```

I would find this very useful.  The problems are

1. It doesn't work, instead giving me `line 36: Bad configuration option: HostnameSuffixes`
2. I cannot find it documented in the `ssh_config` man page, or *anywhere* on the web.  Since several people in the thread—all clearly very knowledgable about OpenSSH—discuss it as though it is real, and the discussion is more than a year old (so it could not very well only exist in an alpha version), I'm assuming that it is real.

Did one of them mistakenly misspell or mis-remember the keyword, and the others just repeat the mistake?  What is the correct keyword?  And where can I find documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole discussion is about a hypothetical option that was proposed, not about an actual feature. In the end the proposed patch uses a different name `ExpandHost`, but again that patch was only proposed, it was never applied to the OpenSSH source code..

What I do is to generate my `.ssh/config` from a shell script. I have functions like

```
home leguin
home williams
work larch
work chestnut
```

which generate stanzas like

```
Host leguin
HostName leguin.gilles.name
UserName gilles

Host williams
HostName williams.gilles.name
UserName gilles

Host larch
HostName larch.acme.com
UserName employee123

Host chestnut
HostName chestnut.acme.com
UserName employee123
```

Comment: Yes, but the change initially proposed was not `HostnameSuffixes`, so it appeared to me that that was an existing keyword.  Apparently, if I understand you correctly, you're saying that `HostnameSuffixes` was being *implicitly* also proposed as another change, but never explicitly mentioned as such?

Comment: @iconoclast `HostnameSuffixes` was explicitly proposed as a change somewhere mid-thread: “A better option might be to allow specification of the suffix order in 
ssh_config itself. E.g. `HostnameSuffixes mel.int.spectre.com int.spectre.com spectre.com`”

Comment: Okay, I missed that mention of it... I guess that's fairly clear there that it's a new option.  Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the sort of thing you're doing in your examples be accomplished as well with `Host leguin williams`\n
`HostName %h.gilles.name`\n
`UserName gilles`?

Comment: @iconoclast Yes, in this case. There are many special cases (with subdomains, etc.) that I haven't shown here. But mostly I think the `%h` variable didn't exist back when I wrote this script.